# does scoreboard condition not work with loot chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i got this in a loot table on a mob it works fine but in a chest its just empty is there a way for them both to work with scoreboard scores of the player

```
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "condition": "entity_scores",
                        "entity": "killer_player",
                        "scores": {
                            "crate": 0
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `entity_scores` with chests as there is no `entity` value you can input to allow it to work.

`killer_player` is only used when a mob is killed, referencing the player that struck the mob in the last 3 seconds. `killer` is the entity that dealt the killing blow to the mob and doesn't have to be a player. `this` would be the mob that was killed.

Comment: so scoreboards cant effect chest loot?

Comment: @dinidini Try using a selector like `@p` instead of `killer_player`. I don't know if it works, but it's my best guess.

Comment: @FabianRöling The value must explicitly be one of `killer_player`, `killer`, or `this`. Selectors will not work.